# Insertar datos de formulario en una base de datos

Tags: html

Tengo una duda respecto a mi formulario, lo que necesito hacer, es que al momento de que llene los campos de mi formulario, este los envie a mi base de datos y quede registrada la persona, pero cuando le doy en registrar no me redirecciona y solo parece como si se recargara la pagina.

este es mi formulario

```
<form action="recibir.php" id="register" method="POST"class="input-group"
```

> cambio actualizado

```
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <input type="text" name="fullname"  id="fullname"class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" required>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <input type="text" name="user_name id="user_name" class="form-control"  placeholder="Usuario" autocomplete="off" required>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <input type="text" name="user_email" id="user_email" class="form-control" placeholder="Correo" required>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <input type="password" name="user_password" id="user_password_hash" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>

        <div>
          <h3>Categoria</h3>
          <br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="check" onclick="onlyOne(this)"><label style="padding-right: 10px;">Fan</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="check" onclick="onlyOne(this)"><label style="padding-right: 10px;">Artista</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="check" onclick="onlyOne(this)"><label style="padding-right: 10px;">Foro</label>

        </div>

        <input type="checkbox" class="chech-box"><span>I agree to terms & conditions</span>
        <button type="submit" class="submit-btn" name="regist">Register</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

y este es mi hoja donde esta la funcion de almacenar datos:

```
if(isset($_POST['regist'])){
 if(strlen($_POST['user_name']) >=1  && strlen($_POST['user_email']) >=1){/*preguntar si estos dos campos estan vacios*/
    $fullname = trim($_POST['fullname']); 
    $user_name = trim($_POST['user_name']);
        $user_email = trim($_POST['user_email']);
        $usee_password = trim($_POST['user_password']);
        $date_add = date("d/m/y");
        $consulta = "INSERT INTO users(fullname,user_name,user_password_hash,user_email, date_added) VALUES ('$fullname',$user_name','$user_name','$date_add')";/*inserta datos en los campos*/
        $resultado = mysqli_query($con,$consulta);
        if($resultado){
            ?>
             <h3 class = "ok">¡Registrado Correctamente! </h3>
            <?php
        } else {
            ?>
                <h3 class="bad">Error en el registro</h3>
            <?php
        }
        
    }
}
```

esta es mi base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de antemano gracias, estare al pendiente de sus sugerencias!

Comment: Te hace hace falta el atributo action para indicar a donde debe viajar la información

Comment: Tal y como dice BetaM, en el form, para poder usarlo, debes mandar el action, si lo mandas a la misma página o a otra. Luego esos datos se deben rescatar, y puedes usarlo.

Comment: ¿en que parte del form va el action? ¿Va en el botón? Mi duda es porque es la primera vez que hago un registro en un formulario.

Comment: En la etiqueta del formulario, va el action.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Answer (score 0):

Para poder utilizar el form correctamente necesitas tener su action y el method, y así poder enviar la información con el uso de POST o GET.

Lo sgte sería la página que envía los datos:

```
//Página enviar.php
<form action="recibir.php" method="POST"> //Formulario que enviaremos a recibir.php
  <input type="text" name="dato" id="dato"> //El dato enviado
  <button type="submit">Enviar Datos</button> //El boton de submit
</form>
```

Y esta sería quien recibe dicha información:

```
//Página recibir.php
<?php
  if(isset($_POST["dato"])){ //Verificamos que la variable esta seteada
    $dato = $_POST["dato"]; //La guardamos dentro de una variable mas amigable
    echo $dato; //Ya que esta guardada, la podemos imprimir
  }
?>
```

Comment: Agregre el action en el form, sin embargo me sigue redireccionando a esa misma pagina, edite el documento para ubicar en donde puse el action, separe mi codigo a una nueva hoja, para no confundirme y la llame de igual manera como la de excorpion.

Comment: Al decirte que lo envie a recibir.php, me refiero a TU página que lo recibe XD. No creo que tengas un documento de ese nombre.